# Automated builds with Visual Studio Online (Azure) for an on-premise server not accessible externally?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, webdeploy, azure-devops

If an on-premise app server has internet access but isn't accessible externally, what is our options for automated builds with Visual Studio Online (Azure)? We have vms for our development web and sql environments on Azure with TFS online housing our source control.

Comment: Do you mean you want to build an application with VSO and deploy it to an on-premise server which is on Azure but can't access externally?

Comment: That's correct. Can the on-premise server call VSO by internet and pull  builds down? Deos Azure allow calls by internet to perform code downloads?

Comment: @Chaka, is your app server hosted on premise or on Azure VM?

Comment: @Chaka, if would like to deploy your app to VM on Azure, please check my reply below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a check on this article for detailed steps on how to publish app to Azure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/

Core steps is: On the Azure Management portal, connect the project to Azure via selecting your app and choosing the Set up publishing with Visual Studio Online link.

Comment: Hi Vicky, just wanted to clarify. The VMs on azure are our DEV environment and Staging/Prod are on-premise. Right now, we need a way to send continuous builds to the on-premise servers. Internet access is available on one server and we need a way to pull builds via internet from azure to a drop location?

Comment: Any suggestion on how to push builds on-premise to staging or prod from the drop location after we pull from azure?

Comment: Using visual studio 2013 as our IDE and framework 4.5.1.

Comment: One last item, would secure FTP be an option (setup on premise)? Can azure drop builds on premise thru secure FTP?

Comment: @Chaka, please check this article for the details information on how to create a virtual network and a site-to-site VPN connection to your on-premises network. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-site-to-site-create/

Answer (score 0):

VSO agents work on a pull bases and don't need to be accessible externally. As long as the build server has internet access you are good to go...

Comment: Any example or articles that may help set it up...I couldn't really find one so far?